# Video in twig modal ist not playing 'No video with supported format and MIME type found'

Tags: php, symfony, video, twig, sonata

I have rendered a twig page from the Controller, in Sonata, and I have the video in it. The video does not play and I get the error in Firefox 'No video with supported format and MIME type found'.

I put the video tag in a dummy html page and it's fine.

```html
    <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="/store/tvdelivery.ro/media/preview/3cefd43df26316158e48359155b4cdeae3ba3e7c.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

Comment: @mimailcornescu: Is it possible that Sonata/Twig (sorry, I don't know these) is using some sort of client-side templating/replacement? It is possible that the `video` element is rendered before `src` attribute on `source` tag is set.